# simple c++ program does not run

Tags: c++, codeblocks

While doing programming in Code::Blocks it does not compile for  C++. Even for a this kind of a simple program.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
   cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

it gives those errors.

```
=== Build: Debug in start (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===

obj\Debug\start.o||In function `main':
C:\Users\dp\Desktop\c++\start\start.cpp|4|multiple definition of `main'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\dp\Desktop\c++\start\main.cpp|6|first defined here
error: ld returned 1 exit status
=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6 second(s)) ===
```

what can i do to fix this.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Judging by your command line you seem to be linking together multiple object files, of which each contain a separate `main` function (thus multiple definition).

Comment: @tambre how ever the there is no syntax error. so this sode must run and show the out put. but it doesn't. how can i fix this

Comment: Having no syntax error doesn't mean that your code must be able to link without problems. The fix is basically stated by my comment - don't link together multiple objects with the same definitions.

Comment: @tambre but this code runs in other computers. does not run in mine. i reinstall the code blocks. but the errors are same.

Comment: Presumably because on other computers you aren't linking with another object file. Please provide your command line for invoking the compiler.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: The message states that you have one file `start.cpp` and one file `main.cpp`, **both** containing a `main` function. So it doesn't know where the program is to start. Now think about how you could resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

As-is the code itself should compile fine. But as the error suggests you have multiple `int main()` function definitions across multiple source files. One is in the *start.cpp* and the other is in the *main.cpp* file. Either keep only one `main()` entry point or compile a single file. Compile with `g++` front-end, not with `gcc`.

Comment: problem is ,this code runs in other computers. but does not run in mine.

Comment: i dont get it. how do i show those files and compilation string.

Comment: which IDE are you using.

Comment: you failed to mention your errors list. what are those errors

Comment: @Frrank those are the errors .                                                                                 .obj\Debug\start.o||In function `main':
C:\Users\dp\Desktop\c++\start\start.cpp|4|multiple definition of `main'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\dp\Desktop\c++\start\main.cpp|6|first defined here
error: ld returned 1 exit status